# VBS window reposition

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to reposition a window with a specific title to a certain spot on my screen. How can I achieve this using VBS. Any amount of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done in VBScript. May I suggest using something like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for this kind of task?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reposition a msgbox or inputbox dialog in VBS, you're better option is to use either the *InternetExplorer.Application* or *TPFSoftware.ScriptDialog* objects to create you're own dialog/window.

**IE App ref:** http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/07/19/how-can-i-create-a-custom-dialog-box.aspx 
**TPFSoftware:** http://tpfsoftware.com/webhelp/products/scriptdialogs10/htmldlg040.html